Docker containers not able to communicate with each other on the same machine
I have a docker compose file running 2 different services and i have launched a third container which is acting as a database for the first two containers.
Third container is a vector db and when i am trying to communicate via the new instantiated docker container i am getting the below error:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send
whisperfusion-1  |     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
whisperfusion-1  | requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

How can i manage communication between both docker containers.
My docker compose file:
version: '3.8'

services:
  service1:

    build:
      context: docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      
    image: service1:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./docker/scratch-space
        target: /root/scratch-space
      - type: bind
      
    environment:
      VERBOSE: ${VERBOSE:-false}
      DB_HOST: host.docker.internal  
      DB_PORT: 3306                 
      DB_USER: '4545'
      DB_PASSWORD: '4545'
      DB_NAME: 'fszdz'
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
      - "6006:6006"
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - capabilities: ["gpu"]

    entrypoint: ["/root"]

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./docker/resources/docker/default:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./docker/scripts/start-nginx.sh:/start-nginx.sh:ro

    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - service1
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "/start-nginx.sh"]

I am starting other service with the below command:
docker run -p 8888:8888 epsilla/vectordb

How to communicate between two containers?
Do i need to rebuild the docker image and what chnages are required to establish the link?

Why don't you add vectordb to the docker-compose so they share the same network by default?

Actually that's a good idea, I didn't think of it.

Did not work still the same issue

and if you docker compose up vectordb and then docker compose up service1 nginx ? Sometimes databases take a while to get going so composing everything at the same time brings errors

Got it working. Restarted the docker service and there a bit of code correction.

Nice! I'm glad it worked
